# Why do Christians use "Lord" and "God" instead of "Yehueh" and "Elohim"?

Tags: names-of-god, greek, aramaic

*Sefer Ha-Mitzvoth of Maimonides*, Volume two, Negative Commandment 63: "Neither shalt thou profane the name of they God: I am the Lord." Lev. XVIII, 21. "And you shall not let any of your seed pass through the fire to Molek, neither shall you profane את eth-the name of your ELOHIYM: I am YAHUAH." Leviticus 18:21, *eth-Cepher*. את "eth" appears many times in the Scriptures, א (tau) ת (alep) in Hebrew order, is "beginning to end" in English order. The LXX came about circa 300 B.C. Subsequently, the Jews compromised with Greek philosophy, and by 265 B.C. placed a ban on using the Set-Apart Names, *Yehueh* and *Elohim*, and replaced them with *Lord* and *God* (and variations thereof). Those substitutions are found in nearly all English translations of Scripture. "And you shall not swear by My Name to a falsehood; nor shall you pollute the name of your Elohim; I AM Yehueh." Leviticus 19:12, *eth-Cepher*. "You shall not take the name of Yehueh your Elohim in vain; for Yehueh will not leave unpunished the one who takes His name in vain." Exodus 20:7. "How long shall this be in the heart of the prophets that prophesy lies? yea, they are prophets of the deceit of their own heart; Which think to cause את eth-my people to forget my name by their dreams which they tell every man to his neighbour, as their fathers have forgotten my name for Ba`al." Yermeyahu 23:26-27, *eth-Cepher*. During the times since the Dead Sea Scroll were found, hundreds, if not thousands more writings have been found that prove the original Hebrew and Aramaic truths have been highjacked by the traditions brought from the Judeo-Greco-Roman-Latin as seen in our Bibles. Why does this practice continue? Why are our leaders, pastors, and teachers not restoring these Set-Apart Names in our churches? Shalom.

Answer (score 4):

> And how hear we **every man in our own tongue,** wherein we were born? Parthians, and Medes, and Elamites, and the dwellers in Mesopotamia, and in Judaea, and Cappadocia, in Pontus, and Asia, Phrygia, and Pamphylia, in Egypt, and in the parts of Libya about Cyrene, and strangers of Rome, Jews and proselytes, Cretes and Arabians, **we do hear them speak in our tongues** the wonderful works of God. And they were all amazed . . . . . .

[Acts 2:8-12 KJV]

When the apostles preached the gospel in this inaugurational event, every man heard the gospel in his own tongue.

We who speak the English language express the names of God, Father, Lord, Jesus, Jesus Christ and Lord Jesus Christ in our own language.

---

In the passage above, sixteen localities are mentioned, a significantly symbolic number in scripture, four being figurative of the earth (north, south, east and west).

I suggest that the hearing of the gospel is to be over the whole of this present earth (in every tongue and throughout every nation) which will multiply (four times four) the number of persons (to an innumerable measure) who shall be present in the world that is yet to come.

> ... And, lo, a great multitude, which no man could number, of **all nations, and kindreds, and people, and tongues**, stood before the throne, and before the Lamb, clothed with white robes, and palms in their hands; 10And cried with a loud voice, saying, Salvation to our God which sitteth upon the throne, and unto the Lamb.

[Revelation 7:9-10 KJV](https://biblehub.com/kjv/revelation/7.htm)
[Acts 2:8-12 KJV](https://biblehub.com/kjv/acts/2.htm)